# What does a MapReduce comparison function do?

Tags: mapreduce

I understand the mapping and the reducing, but I don't understand what the comparison phase of a MapReduce cycle offers. Does it simply collect mapper output and group emitted documents by key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This phase sorts and groups mapped values by their keys.